# Equal Height Multiple Selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found the following script on Codepen and adapted it for a project I am working on: https://codepen.io/RogerHN/pen/YNrpVa

I basically changed the selector:

```
        var matchHeight = function () {

            function init() {
                eventListeners();
                matchHeight();
            }

            function eventListeners(){
                $(window).on('resize', function() {
                    matchHeight();
                });
            }

            function matchHeight(){
                var groupName = $('#services h3');
                var groupHeights = [];
    
                groupName.css('min-height', 'auto');
    
                groupName.each(function() {
                    groupHeights.push($(this).outerHeight());
                });
    
                var maxHeight = Math.max.apply(null, groupHeights);
                groupName.css('min-height', maxHeight);
            };

            return {
                init: init
            };

        } ();

        $(document).ready(function() {
            matchHeight.init();
        });
```

I have seen lots of equal height scripts, but alot of them don't work when I resize my screen from a small window size to a big window size. This script does, but when I add multiple selectors it doesn't work as expected.

I tried `var groupName = $('#services h3, #services .info');` which works, but makes all the h3's and all the .info's the same height. So, if the tallest h3 is 100px and the largest .info is 500px, all of the h3's and the .info's become 500px. What I would like is the h3's to all become 100px (since that's the largest h3) and all of the .info's to become 500px (since that's the largest .info.

I'm not sure how to explain it. But this is grabbing all of the selectors and seeing them all as one selection rather than keeping the two selectors separate and just applying the script within a specific selector, which is what I was envisioning.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: When you ask JQuery to select a collection of objects (i.e. `$('<selector>')`) it does just that, create a single collection of all the objects you selected.  The CSS comma operator does not cause the creation of multiple collections, it's just accumulating all the objects from all selectors to put in the the single collection being returned.  You probably want to create a function that takes a selector and a height and call it once for every type of object you want to modify (i.e `('#services h3', 100)` and `('#services .info', 500)`).

Comment: I almost have it working now. I was able to find some code that executes on resize, so everything is working except for on ready. But my window.onresize breaks if I add a document.ready. Any ideas on how I could write a document.ready so my window.onresize still works? I'm guessing one is canceling the other one out. I updated my code above so you can see what I have.

Comment: It's generally not a good idea to change your question (except to clarify) after you've asked it, since it's actually then a different question.

Comment: I removed the secondary code, I am trying to get this working. My updated code was not a complete departure from what I was trying to do, it was just doing things differently. I do see how that would be confusing, I have gone ahead and removed my update. I'll try and get the original code working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting everything into the selector makes jquery thinks all of them as one. My suggestion is make the function receives selectors serparately:

```
   function matchHeight(selector){
    var groupName = $(selector);
```

and call the it on each selector:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    matchHeight.init();
    matchHeight.matchHeight('#some-id');
    matchHeight.matchHeight('.some-class');
});
```

Hopefully it works.